# Lenovo Mice N700 mapping

Tags: lenovo, xmodmap

I've got a Lenovo Mice N700, which was built for Windows 8. It works perfectly on Ubuntu (16.04), but has 2 flaws: swipes.

On Windows 8, they were supposed to trigger actions just like touchscreen/touchpad edge swipes. The thing is that it is mapped to `C` and `Backspace` keys (with weird order of modifiers sent). I would like to remap it to `Alt + Left Arrow` and `Alt + Right Arrow`. Would that be possible?

Here is the xev output:

LEFT TO RIGHT:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xd3, subw 0x0, time 89047051, (1281,352), root:(1318,453),
    state 0x4050, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xd3, subw 0x0, time 89047066, (1281,352), root:(1318,453),
    state 0x4054, keycode 22 (keysym 0xff08, BackSpace), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (08) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xd3, subw 0x0, time 89047066, (1281,352), root:(1318,453),
    state 0x4054, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xd3, subw 0x0, time 89047066, (1281,352), root:(1318,453),
    state 0x4014, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

RIGHT TO LEFT:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xd3, subw 0x0, time 89193252, (1370,422), root:(1407,523),
    state 0x4010, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xd3, subw 0x0, time 89193267, (1370,422), root:(1407,523),
    state 0x4050, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0xd3, subw 0x0, time 89193267, (1370,422), root:(1407,523),
    state 0x4050, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```